# pitch yaw roll, angle independency

Tags: c++, opengl, transformation, jogl, angle

I am trying hard to figure out how to make pitch yaw and roll independent between them.
As soon as I rotate something in the z axis (pitch) the second rotation (yaxis yaw) depends on the results of the first and the third rotation (x axis, roll) depends on the other two. So instead of having independent pitch,yaw,roll I get a mixture of the three of them, ugly.

I wish it was possible to store the object angles in an array [pitch,yaw,roll] and then decode those angles during the transformation so that yawing put the object in a given position and then it took the angle corresponding to the pitch, but not a compound of both...

I have seen references to an 'arbitrary axis rotation matrix'. Would it be useful to get the desired results???
1) apply yaw (gl.glRotatef(beta, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);)
2) get the resulting axis of manually rotating the vector (1.0f,0.0f,0.0f) arround beta
3) apply pitch using the axis got in 2
{and for roll... if 1,2,3 are correct}
4) rotate the axis got in 2 arround its x for a roll
5) apply roll using the axis got in 4

Would it work? Any better solution? I would like keeping my object local orientations in the [pitch,yaw,roll] format.

I have been struggling with it for days, I would like to avoid using quaternions if possible. The 3D objects are stored relatively to 0,0,0 and looking along {1,0,0} and transformed to their destination and angles each frame, so the gimbal lock problem should probably be avoided easily.

In other words, my camera is working fine, World coordinates are being correctly made, but I do not know how or where object-local-transformations based on yaw,pith,roll should be applied.

The results should be read from the array [y,p,r] and combinations of them **should not overlap**.

Actually my transformations are:

```
gl.glLoadIdentity(); 
float[] scalation = transform.getScalation();
gl.glScalef(scalation[0], scalation[1], scalation[2]); 
float[] translation = transform.getTranslation();
gl.glTranslatef(translation[0], translation[1], translation[2]);
float[] rotation = transform.getRotation();
gl.glRotatef(rotation[0], 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gl.glRotatef(rotation[1], 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
gl.glRotatef(rotation[2], 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: why do you want to avoid quaternions ?

Comment: "I would like keeping my object local orientations in the [pitch,yaw,roll] format." Why? And why discount the actual solution to the problem (ie: quaternions)?

Comment: I want to keep the code as simple as possible and quaternions would probably add complexity. Trying to figure out where the quaternion-based code would fit in the actual code and doubts about if they should accompany or replace the actual rotation code makes me try to avoid them, the documents I have found tell about how they work mathematically but do not give any examples of where do they fit in an already done euler based code. Rotations are complex enough and discarding what mistakes are due to angles and which ones are due to implementation errors is sometimes quite hard.

Answer (score 7):

The orientation always depends on angles order. You can't make them indipendent. You rotate vectors multipling them by matrices, and matrix multiplication is not commutative. You can choose one order and be consistent with it.
For these problems, a common choice is the ZYX orientation method (first roll, then pitch and at the end yaw).
My personal reference when I work with angles is [this document](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/mzucker1/e27/diebel2006attitude.pdf), that helps me a lot.

EDIT:

I've seen that actually the link is not correct. A working link for the document that I use is the following one:

[Representing Attitude: Euler Angles, Unit Quaternions, and Rotation
Vectors](https://www.astro.rug.nl/software/kapteyn-beta/_downloads/attitude.pdf)

Answer (score 4):

if you use yaw/pitch/roll, your final orientation will always depend on the amounts and order in which you apply them.  you can choose other schemes if you want readability or simplicity.  i like choosing a forward vector (F), and calculating a right and up vector based on a canonical 'world up' vector, then just filling in the matrix columns.  You could add an extra 'axis spin' angle term, if you like.  It's a bit like a quaternion, but more human-readable.  I use this representation for controlling a basic WASD-style camera.

Comment: @Danielle Lupo Thanks for the document, looks amazing. I am just trying to simulate the movement of an airplane as if it was controlled from the cockpit, not from outside. Imagine I do a loop while(true){ incement_yaw(1); increment_pitch(1);} I would then like to get a continuously rotating arround 'the floor' airplane that is continuosly looping 'through the air', and not a mixture of both. Is that possible? Are my 'mixed' results due to using euler angles (gimbal lock)? **would quaternions solve my problem?**

Comment: yes, quaternions help here, but it's not so simple.  first, try your method and see what happens.  you'll find that it doesn't quite look right, not very physical.  there are several things to consider: the absolute position & orientation of the plane (relative to the ground), and the linear velocity & angular velocity as well.  euler angles are a bad choice for representing orientation, but they make a little more sense when talking about making small adjustments to orientation or angular velocity.

Comment: the problem in this case is not quaternions vs. matrices (euler angles are definitely wrong), it's how you model your plane.  in your case, you might want to ignore angular velocity, so matrices would work just as well as quaternions. matrices may be easier for you to visualize, too (the columns are the right/forward/up vectors, depending on the coordinate system you have chosen).

Comment: Quaternion are faster than matrice for calculus and are more intuitive because you can associate three rotation angles with one mathematical entity and they can be rotate by quaternion multiplication. They are also useful for rotation interpolation (slerp). But their construction from rotation angles also depend on coordinate system. In literature is widely used construction from ZYX convention, so be careful with it.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulating (yaw, pitch, roll) rotations requires to keep a transformation matrix, which is the product of the separate transformations, in the order in which they occur. The resulting matrix is a rotation around some axis and some angle.